# Хосты и организация папок + поддержка доменов 3го уровня

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod_rewrite, php

Начну издвлека.
 Система windows 7.
 Установил apache2.2, прикрутил к нему php5_module.
 В httpd.conf AllowOverride All для чтения .htaccess.

 Содержимое его:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteBase /

<Files .*>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny From All
</Files>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !(.js|.css|.png|.gif|.jpg|.jpeg)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Суть вот в чем. у меня в каталоге htdocs есть каталог project.com с проектом, а значит запуск его осуществляется по урлу вида http://localhost/project.com/index.php. НО необходимо сделать так, чтоб проект был доступен по адресу http://project.com. Также нужна поддержка доменов 3го уровня вида http://subdomain.project.com. 
Вопрос: как быть? 
Еще, чтоб вопросов не плодить, спрошу здесь. 
 
Есть острая необходимость сделать так, чтобы если у меня есть каталог htdocs/project.com/system и обратиться по адресу http://project.com/system, то чтоб "/system" попала в `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ставьте [денвер](http://www.denwer.ru/) он сам все делает, либо изучайте [virtual hosts](http://zavu.ru/cI5uABZ/)

Comment: Да. Уже сходил туда) а денвер ставить, если только очень лень или проект типа "форма авторизации". Для сложных лучше всё своими ручками, как говорится, по-человечески, настроить.

Comment: ну да, денвер это для отладки. Если вам рабочий режим нужен - тогда только виртуал хостс.

Comment: @Ozim - я бы перефразировал... <br>
только виртуал хостс - коротко и ясно 66

Answer (score 1):

Популярный вопрос, хоть вики делай :)

[Тут](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/8015/) описано как сделать такое. Вы не смущайтесь что там речь о unix. Под винду тоже самое сделать можно